# Why is wrapping happening between consecutive blocks despite spaces in the block?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

Say you want to create a form with labels for your input, and want to make it somehow responsive by displaying as many inputs along with their labels on each line. In order to do this, I thought about the automatic space wrapping : **no space between labels and inputs, but space between each group**.

```html
<body>
    <form>
        <label for="aa">AA</label><input type="text" name="aa" id="aa" />
        <label for="bb">BB</label><input type="text" name="bb" id="bb" />
        <label for="cc">CC</label><input type="text" name="cc" id="cc" />
        <label for="dd">DD</label><input type="text" name="dd" id="dd" />
        <label for="ee">EE</label><input type="text" name="ee" id="ee" />
        <label for="ff">FF</label><input type="text" name="ff" id="ff" />
    </form>
</body>
```

As you can see, there is a space between each "group" of label+input due to the line break. But that does not seem to be OK for automatic wrapping as is seems wrapping is done between inputs and labels almost always. What I want is to wrap at the space, not between the label and the input!

What am I doing wrong ? Although I know wrapping each group in another item would work, I'd like to keep my code as light as possible. I tried some CSS, but did not manage to arrange this.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this can be achieved by wrapping the input tags inside the labels and adding a CSS rule to labels :

```css
label{
  white-space:nowrap;
  }
```

```html
<body>
    <form>
        <label for="aa">AA<input type="text" name="aa" id="aa" /></label>
        <label for="bb">BB<input type="text" name="bb" id="bb" /></label>
        <label for="cc">CC<input type="text" name="cc" id="cc" /></label>
        <label for="dd">DD<input type="text" name="dd" id="dd" /></label>
        <label for="ee">EE<input type="text" name="ee" id="ee" /></label>
        <label for="ff">FF<input type="text" name="ff" id="ff" /></label>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way without any extra markup would be to use `float` and `clear`.

```
label,
input {
    float: left;
}

label {
    clear: left;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j75s4zax/)

Comment: The OP clearly stated that he wants wrapping between each label + input but without additional markup. Maybe it is not what he is looking for but thats what was asked.

Comment: *"want to make it somehow responsive by displaying **as many inputs along with their labels on each line**"*.  This method only displays one set per line.

Comment: He also states, "_What I want is to wrap at the space, not between the label and the input!_"

Comment: I'm sure the OP will clarify when he returns and we can find the solution he needs.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question, this answer indeed does not fit my needs. What I want is the result of the other answers (display as many label+input on one line, not ONE input+label per line) without using the divs, but that does not seem to be possible.

Answer (score 1):

The OP wants the elements label+input to wrap as one element, even though they are not. So when re-sizing the window, it doesn't need to separate label and input into separate lines. I do not know of anyway to do this without wrapping them in another element such as:
https://jsfiddle.net/goscuon5/

```
div { display: inline-block; }
```

Or you could use an element that has a default property of display: inline-block;

I don't think it's possible otherwise.

Comment: that was my answer as well.

Comment: Yours will not have them display on one line though, this answer will, which I think the OP was wanting this behavior. If not, your answer works.

Comment: Well. It says "Say you want to create a form with labels for your input, and want to make it somehow responsive by displaying as many inputs along with their labels on each line." He wants to display as many inputs as he can on one line.

Comment: Correct. That is my answer. One line, but it wraps the label+input together as the OP wanted. Your code adds them all on their OWN line, not on ONE line.

Comment: it does.. i added the css outside of the snippet. but now I integrated it. Our answers were the same.

Comment: Indeed, your answers are the same now. I wanted to achieve this result without additional markup but it does not seem possible so I'll use this.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div { display:inline-block; }
```

```html
<body>
    <form>
       <div> <label for="aa">AA</label><input type="text" name="aa" id="aa" /></div>
        <div>  <label for="bb">BB</label><input type="text" name="bb" id="bb" /> </div>
        <div>  <label for="cc">CC</label><input type="text" name="cc" id="cc" /> </div>
        <div>  <label for="dd">DD</label><input type="text" name="dd" id="dd" /> </div>
       <div>   <label for="ee">EE</label><input type="text" name="ee" id="ee" /> </div>
       <div>   <label for="ff">FF</label><input type="text" name="ff" id="ff" />  </div> 
    </form>
</body>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

and with css do `div { display:inline-block; }` or div { float:left; }

Comment: Sometimes working and implementation does not relate.

Comment: Hm. I didn't implement anything. Looks like there's people that don't contribute yet come to bother other people here.

Comment: This solution outputs exactly the same as the OP's posted code.

Comment: Not really. The labels are grouped with the inputs here.. I think it's best if he clarifies what he is trying to achieve.

Comment: My objective is to achieve this result without additional markup, but as it does not seem to be possible, I will use this.

Comment: Thank god you answered. We were getting into arguments here.